# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been getting the error above when calling function that uses ajax on production server. The code of the function is:

```js
function check() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/check/',
    data: JSON.stringify(events),
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var data_ = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      
      if (data_["overdues"].length === 0) {
        showAlert('OK', "alert-success");
      } else {
        make_conflicts_table(data_["overdues"]);
        showAlert('OK', "alert-info");
      }
      console.log('Chech return : success');
      console.log('Display presented')
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Chech return : error');
      showAlert('Not OK', "alert-danger");
    }
  });
}
```

The code works fine on localhost but not on the server. I have checked that events are in correct json syntax. Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: The code you've shown does not display that error. My guess would be that it's the JSON you receive from the AJAX request causing the problem. Check the responseText of the request in dev tools and validate that it's correctly formatted JSON

Comment: Also note that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is entirely redundant. The output will be the same as `data`, so just work with that directly.

Comment: The JSON is valid. Everything works fine until I call the function. And it works fine on localhost but when deployed to the server, the error occurs

Comment: check console, debug it, dump $_POST in check function, and also return with json_encode if not

Comment: @NikaK just to confirm, you said in the question that the *request* JSON is valid, I'm talking about the *response* JSON. Have you checked that?

Comment: @AhmedSunny you're assuming the OP is working with a PHP backend